# Custom Post type plugin breaking the front page shows dashboard?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, errors

I am following the wp.tutsplus tutorial on Custom post types. Everything was fine until i added this code in my main plugin file

```
<?php add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_template_function', 1);?>

<?php function include_template_function(){
    if( get_post_type() == 'movie_reviews' ){
        if( is_single() ){
            if( $theme_file = locate_template( 'single-movie-reviews.php' ) ){
                $template_path = $theme_file;
            }
            else 
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'single-movie-reviews.php';
        }
    }
    return $template_path;
}
?>
```

I can still access the dashboard and create new posts but front page is blank. if i remove this code page loads without any problem.

Comment: What if you add `$template_path` to your function, like: `function include_template_function( $template_path ) {`?

Comment: Oh man, i spent 2 pomodoros on this thing. Page is loading now. But it doesn't appear in the page template dropdown list.

Comment: If `movie-reviews` is a CPT, `single-movie-reviews.php` should be loaded auto-magically. Why are you doing this manually and why do you need it to show up in the template dropdown?

Comment: I am following this tutorial http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/a-guide-to-wordpress-custom-post-types-creation-display-and-meta-boxes/

Comment: @s_ha_dum I want to add a page called Movie Reviews which will show all the reviews and for that i need to use the Movie reviews template.

Comment: Yes, but WordPress will load a file named `single-movie-reviews.php` ___automatically___ for single Movie Review (CPT named `movie-reviews`) posts, or will load `archive-movie-reviews.php` for the archive listing. So far, I can't tell why any of this is necessary. Maybe that is the answer. None of this is necessary, but I am trying to understand what you are doing before jumping to that conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To solve your issue with the page template not showing up in the template dropdown list

In your `single-movie-reviews.php`, add the following at the top of the file:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/
```

Where you change `My Custom Page` into the template name of your choice.

See [**This Codex page**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template) for more information about Custom Page Templates.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress will load a file named `single-movie-reviews.php` ***automatically*** for single Movie Review (CPT named `movie-reviews`) posts, or will load `archive-movie-reviews.php` for the archive listing. See the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) Codex page.

That `template_include` filter appears to me to be doing (or attempting to do) exactly what the Core does automatically. I have no idea what its purpose it. Just leave that part out and name your files appropriately so that the WordPress Core can do its job.